# What is the difference between CC-BY-SA with attribution and MIT with attribution?

Tags: licensing

You may have seen [The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) and [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required/).

But I'm no legal expert, and I'm confused what the changes would include. What's the difference between CC-By-SA and MIT, and what about with attribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the difference is the "sharealike" clause of CC-BY-SA.  Any derivative of a CC-BY-SA work must itself be licensed CC-BY-SA, whereas a derivative of an "MIT with attribution" work can be under any license the author wants.

There are a number of other differences in the fine print (eg. CC forbids DRM, where MIT doesn't), but that's the big one.

Comment: Do any of them address parents? I remember GPL does, how about MIT and CC-BY-SA?

Comment: @Viktor, MIT says nothing about patents; CC-BY-SA merely notes that the license covers copyright only, not patent or trademark rights.